# Duvida sobre CSS e posicionamentos

Tags: css

Vamos supor que vou posicionar uma `div` `100px` de `height` e `width`, (um quadrado) então eu posiciono este quadrado em `margin-left 40%` e `margin-top 20%`, o quadrado esta mais ou menos centralizado, certo? Agora vou colocar um texto escrito "oi" dentro dele com a tag `<p>`, agora se eu usar a lupa, acontece o seguinte, somente a lateral direita e a parte de baixo do quadrado vão expandir enquanto seus outros dois lados não expande e o texto permanece intacto, digamos que eu quero que tudo expanda sem que as laterais se movam como faria isso ?

Sobre o código que falei acima:

```css
.caracteristicas{
  position: absolute;
  background-color: green;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-left: 40%;
  margin-top: 20%;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Aprendendo a centralizar</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="caracteristicas">
      <p>oi</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Só uma dica, pare enquanto é tempo de usar o`position: absolute`. Tenta centralizar as coisas usando o `position: relative` que vai ter resultados melhores. Mas, se combinar o `absolute` ao `margin`, de uma forma ou outra não está colaborando pra estruturar funcionar. Sempre que usar `absolute` combine com o atributo `left`, `top`, `right`, `bottom`. Algo como `top: 20%` por exemplo.

Comment: No seu exemplo, para deixar o elemento 100% centralizado, redimensionando o navegador ou aplicando a lupa, retire o `position`, troque `margin-left: 40%, margin-top: 20%` por `margin: 20% auto 0 auto`. Isso garante 100% de centralização do objeto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hoje em dia existem algumas técnicas mais responsivas para centralizar uma div na tela, é o caso do sistema de grids.

### Como funciona

Basicamente a ideia do sistema de grids css, copia a ideia de `<tables>`, no qual você trabalha com linhas e colunas.

### O código

Fiz um código simples, na qual a div centralizada é centralizada correspondente ao container dela, que é 100% o tamanho da tela e centralizada horizontalmente por `margin` e verticalmente por `vertical-align`.

Um exemplo rodando:

```css
html, body{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  display: table;
}
.container_centralizado{
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
  position: relative;
}
.centralizado{
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

/** Aqui para baixo é só para fins de estilização, favor ignorar **/

.centralizado{
  color: white;
  background: blue;
}
.centralizado span{
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 3em;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: arial;
}
```

```html
<div class="container_centralizado">
  <div class="centralizado">
    <span>Div Centralizada</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

PS: É sempre interessante usar a [meta tag viewport](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) no seu html. Assim, a partir desse exemplo, quando usada a "lupa", a div fica sempre centralizada, expandindo centralizada.